# iOS Set Date format based on user locale

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to set the date format based on user locale:

So I followed the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676435/how-do-i-format-the-current-date-for-the-users-locale):

Specifically, I did:

```
NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSString* myString = [df stringFromDate:now];
```

My question is: when I set the locale to Italy, the date shows as "24/nov/2014". Why is the month shown as "nov" instead of "11"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSDateFormatterStyle), the "Medium" style (that you are specifying) for English is shown as "Nov 23, 1937" so it shouldn't be very surprising that it was shown as "nov" instead of "11" in Italian.

> `NSDateFormatterMediumStyle`
>   Specifies a medium style, typically with abbreviated text, such as “Nov 23, 1937”"

It looks like maybe you are looking for the "Short" style. Note that some countries present are shown as *day, month, year* while others prefer *year, month, day* or even *month, day, year*<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)</sup> (as seen below):

> `NSDateFormatterShortStyle`
>   Specifies a short style, typically numeric only, such as “11/23/37”

Comment: I mean, it looks weird to have 'nov' when using '/' in Medium Style. I think '/' should be used with numeric. The Medium example 'Nov 23, 1937' makes sense. And in the 'Short' example, all are numbers with '/'. I don't understand why in Italy locale  Medium, why it uses '/' and locale.

Comment: I'm guessing it makes sense to an Italian.